# JSON Jackson flat json to composite java object

Tags: json, jackson

I was wondering if someone could suggest the recommended way to covert flat JSON into a complex java object.
Example JSON

```
{account_id: 1, user_id:3, user_name:john ... }
```

But my java class needs to be

```
class Account {
    int account_id;
    User user;
}
```

And here is the user object...

```
class User {
    int user_id;
    String user_name;
}
```

It looks like I could go from JSON to java using the Jackson constructor to create the object the way I need but I also need to covert the java object into a flat JSON. 
Do I need to use a serializer/deserializer for each class or is there a way I can do it with simple annotations... By maybe telling it to ignore the user object but not what's inside it..

Let me know what your ideas are. Thanks

Comment: So I found some documentation on the annotations and found JsonUnwrapped. It appears I can use this to essentially flatten out my JSON during deserializing does this also handle serializing from a flat JSON string into a complex java object or do I need to setup a special constructor to correctly creat the java object. Suggestions?

Comment: Yes, `@JsonUnwrapped` works both ways; you would use it for your `User user` field (or getter / setter used to access it). And I think it would solve your problem here.

Comment: Can you provide a JavaDoc link? I can't seem to find JsonUnwrapped in the Jackson 2.2 and 2.1 JavaDoc (http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/overview-tree.html
), and you did not specify which version you are using. I can find it in Eclipse, though...

Comment: Ah, there we are, I looked in the wrong place: 
http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html

Comment: One drawback of @JsonUnwrapped, as is documented, is that "Serialization is done using BeanSerializer, not a custom serializer". 
Is there a nice way around it? My own nested class (corresponding to "User" in the example) uses various custom (De)Serializers...